# Elasticsearch update_by_query for array of objects(non nested type)

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic Document

```
[{
  "_id":"1",
  "children":[{
   "test":"1"
   }],
  "test1":"100"
},
{
  "_id":"2",
  "children":[{
   "test":"3"
   }],
  "test1":"101"
}
]
```

```
POST .../_update_by_query
{
  "script":{
      "source":"ctx._source_children[0].test = ctx._source.test1"
   }
}
```

This update query does not work. It gives error "cannot access method/field [normalizeIndex] from a null def reference". What could be the issue?

Comment: Try with a . instead of _ :  ctx._source.children[0].test

Comment: Indeed it seems there is a type in your query the `dot` is missing between `_source` and `children`, you put an `_` instead